# How to put certain font colour in the formula for countif?

Tags: excel, countif

I have a spreadsheet that counts only N's. But I want specific colour (Red) in my countif formula.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Color is a metadata property of a cell that is not exposed to worksheet functions.

Why is the N red? What made it red?

If you manually set the font color to red, then that's bad practice, because the reason exists just in your head and Excel cannot use it for processing.

If the font color is changed to red by conditional formatting, then you can also build a formula with the same logic and use that in a helper cell to serve as the basis for worksheet formula processing.